# Complex find/replace with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to add html links in the following examples:

1. Blah Blah Blah BZ#01234 Blah Blah Blah
2. Blah Blah Blah BZ#0124 Blah Blah Blah
3. Blah Blah Blah BZ 012345 Blah Blah Blah
4. Blah Complex Blah BZ#123 , 345, 567,2341 Blah

So the look like:

1. Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=01234">BZ#01234</a> Blah Blah Blah
2. Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=0124">BZ#0124</a> Blah Blah Blah
3. Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=012345">BZ 012345</a> Blah Blah Blah
4. Blah Complex Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=123">BZ#123</a> , <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=345">345</a>, <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=567">567</a>,<a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2341">2341</a> Blah

So I guess this is a regex job to find the matches, and some PowerShell magic to add the html links. I *think* the regex is `((BZ#)|(BZ ))[0-9]+` to match everything except the complex example, but I dont know regex well enough to be sure, or how to even test it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works, it depends on how variable the input can be.

```
$inputstring = @'
Blah Blah Blah BZ#01234 Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah BZ#0124 Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah BZ 012345 Blah Blah Blah
Blah Complex Blah BZ#123 , 345, 567,2341 Blah
'@

# Split the input into an array of strings
$lines = $inputstring -split '[\r\n]'

# Setup patterns to match against
$pattern1 = "(.*)\sBZ#(\d+) , (\d+), (\d+),(\d+) (.*)"
$pattern2 = "(.*)\sBZ#(\d+)\s(.*)"
$pattern3 = "(.*)\sBZ (\d+)\s(.*)"

# Loop through each line
for($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.count; $i++)
{
    # Start off assuming the current line produces no output
    $output = ""

    # Look for volumes with drive letters
    if($lines[$i] -match $pattern1)
    {
        $output = $matches[1] + " <a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[2] + "`">BZ#" + $matches[2] + "</a> , " + 
            "<a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[3] + "`">" + $matches[3] + "</a>, " + 
            "<a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[4] + "`">" + $matches[4] + "</a>," + 
            "<a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[5] + "`">" + $matches[5] + "</a> " + 
            $matches[6]
    }
    elseif($lines[$i] -match $pattern2)
    {
        $output = $matches[1] + " <a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[2] + "`">BZ#" + $matches[2] + "</a> " + $matches[3]
    }
    elseif($lines[$i] -match $pattern3)
    {
        $output = $matches[1] + " <a href=`"http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=" + $matches[2] + "`">BZ " + $matches[2] + "</a> " + $matches[3]
    }

    # Write out any output that was produced
    if($output -ne "")
    {
        $output
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=01234">BZ#01234</a> Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=0124">BZ#0124</a> Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=012345">BZ 012345</a> Blah Blah Blah
Blah Complex Blah <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=123">BZ#123</a> , <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=345">345</a>, <a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=567">567</a>,<a href="http://bz.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2341">2341</a> Blah
```